# ASP.NET prevent bot/spam attack from a comment form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple contact us / comment from in my website and this form will send email containing the comments, etc after it is submitted. I have used NoBot control from ajaxcontrol toolkit for several times but it seems that this control did not prevent the spam/bot attack 100%.

The client insist that this form should not have any capcha code or something that users have to insert in the form. So what is the best way to handle the spam/bot attack for my current case.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to stop bots, without having anything to tell bots apart from users?

Answer (score 9):

Without a captcha there is no 100% way of stopping all spam. (or even with a captcha)

one method would be to put an input type=text on the page and hide it using css, then if it's filled in when the form is submitted it's spam, any normal user would never even know about the field.

Comment: Yes, agree with you. I think captcha is the best idea to prevent form spam. Are there any case of spam still occures even when using captcha?

Answer (score 0):

Outside of a captcha, the key to stopping bots on small sites is to do something custom.  Bot-writers know their work, and they'll have canned scripts capable of defeating the common and even most of the uncommon systems out there.  You need to do something unique.  It doesn't even have to be that complicated. The person who created this very site was able to get by running a popular blog for years by simply asking his users to type in the word `orange`.

I want to also point out that this doesn't mean you should start from scratch.  As with all security-related code, if you try to do it yourself you'll likely get it wrong.  What you want to do is find a system that gives you source code and customize it for your site, so that existing scripts that know how to defeat that system will no longer work.